# How can I avoid getting stuck after 100 AJAX calls to the same WebMethod from an ASPX page in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

Repeated ajax calls to WebMethod on server got stuck after 100 calls,
It seems thers a boundery in browsers - Chrom/Edge how many ajax calls can be made from the the same aspx page to the same WebMethod

At first I trievd `setInterval(MyAjaxFunc,5000)`
Than tried not to count on the timer and instead call `MyAjaxFunc` recorsively, No use

Comment: Making 100+ AJAX calls to an endpoint is the problem you should look to solve, not the fact they're getting stuck. If you're trying to keep the client and server side state in sync, then AJAX polling is not the ideal solution. I'd suggest you research WebSockets instead. This is far more reliable and scalable.

Comment: Gee, I have to agree with above comment. I often can take 10 ajax calls, and say return the SAME data in ONE call with a serlized object (json), and thus get all the data and stuff I need with one call as opposed to 10 calls. But, a 100 web method calls in one shot? yes, something is wrong here - very wrong. As noted, if one REALLY needs that much "chatter" from the client, then I agree 100% that some kind of web socket approach should be considered here. The  SignalR framework which is based on webSockets for example is a good suggestion here.